# Django: python manage.py migrate --noinput

Tags: django

I am considering to add the command `release: python manage.py migrate --no-input` to my deployment, so Heroku is automatically migrating, once I push my repository. I now wonder if `--no-input` is a 'good' idea?

One more specific question: If migrate normally asks me 'Did you rename this field'. With `--no-input`, will it answer automatically yes? I couldn't find much detailed information in the official Django documentation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We don't use the *interactive* flag (`--no-input`) in our pipeline and to the best of my knowledge it doesn't make much difference. If you inspected Django source code, you would find out that the interactive flag only falls through to the `pre_migrate` and `post_migrate` signals that are emitted prior to and post migration.

As far as I know, no internal Django app uses the interactive argument inside these signals. Some external packages perhaps could use that, but I personally have never encountered that.

As for your question:

> One more specific question: If migrate normally asks me 'Did you rename this field'. With --no-input, will it answer automatically yes? I couldn't find much detailed information in the official Django documentation.

This happens in the `makemigrations` management command, not in `migrate`. You usually do (and should do) the former locally, so no need to include that in your deployment pipeline.

Comment: Great answer, thank you! I mixed makemigrations & migrate.